# JavaFX HTML Editor display raw HTML code on the editor

Tags: java, javafx, html-editor

I was wondering if there's a way to load an HTML file on JavaFx's HTMLEditor but rather then loading it as a web page, show the actual raw source code on the HTMLEditor. Is this possible with JavaFX's HTMLEditor?

I tried the following:

> File f = fc.showOpenDialog(null); //This allows a user to find a file in a dialog
>
> String textRead = readFile(f); //store the files content in a string
>
> htmlFileEditor.setHtmlText(textRead); //displays the source but not as raw HTML

This only loads the html file and displays it, Im wondering if there is a way to show the raw source code of the HTML file loaded with tags and all on the HTMLEditor.

Comment: Html is text so why not simply use a `TextArea`? `HTMLEditor` does not support showing the source html (Mentioned in the javadocs: *"The underlying data model is HTML, although this is not shown visually to the end-user."*)

Comment: I may just use textarea, but I was hoping to open an html file as raw code, then allow the user to modify the text loaded on the HTMLEditor, such as turning the font red, etc..  I was wondering if its possible, but if its not then textarea will work.